# Why does the equation for effectiveness of heat exchangers have $C_{\text{min}}$ in the denominator?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

For an ideal heat exchanger of infinite length,

$$
Q_{max}=m_{h}C_{h}\left[T_{h,i}-T_{o}\right]=m_{c}C_{c}\left[T_{o}-T_{c,i}\right]
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
m_{h}C_{h}T_{h,i}+m_{c}C_{c}T_{c,i} & = & T_{o}\left[m_{h}C_{h}+m_{c}C_{c}\right]\\
T_{o} & = & \frac{m_{h}C_{h}T_{h,i}+m_{c}C_{c}T_{c,i}}{m_{h}C_{h}+m_{c}C_{c}}
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\therefore Q_{max} & = & m_{h}C_{h}\left[T_{h,i}-\frac{m_{h}C_{h}T_{h,i}+m_{c}C_{c}T_{c,i}}{m_{h}C_{h}+m_{c}C_{c}}\right]\\
 & = & m_{h}C_{h}\left[\frac{m_{h}C_{h}T_{h,i}+m_{c}C_{c}T_{h,i}-m_{h}C_{h}T_{h,i}-m_{c}C_{c}T_{c,i}}{m_{h}C_{h}+m_{c}C_{c}}\right]\\
Q_{max} & = & \frac{m_{h}C_{h}m_{c}C_{c}\left[T_{h,i}-T_{c,i}\right]}{m_{h}C_{h}+m_{c}C_{c}}
\end{eqnarray*}
So why does Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTU_method) say 
$$
Q_{max}=\min\left(m_{h}C_{h},m_{c}C_{c}\right)\left[T_{h,i}-T_{c,i}\right]
$$

Comment: This is one case where you may not want to use Wikipedia.  Your graph shows co-current fluid flow, which is inefficient because the driving force for heat transfer is the temperature difference, and a co-current flow situation does not maximize the temperature difference.  Most industrial applications use counter-current fluid flow.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation for $Q_{max}$ gives the heat transferred for *any* ideal exchanger. The equation for $q_{max}$ in the Wiki page gives the heat transferred for *the* ideal exchanger that maximizes the temperature change of *one* of the fluids. The maximum possible temperature change is $T_{h,i} - T_{c,i}$. The max temperature change occurs when either $m_h C_h \ll m_c C_c$ or $m_c C_c \ll m_h C_h$. For the former we get:
$$
Q_{max} = {{m_h C_h m_c C_c [ T_{h,i} - T_{c,i} ]} \over {m_c C_c}}
$$
$$
\therefore Q_{max} = {m_h C_h [ T_{h,i} - T_{c,i} ]}
$$
Which is the heat transferred between the fluids in *the* ideal exchanger that gives the largest change in temperature of the hot fluid. Note that in this case that $T_{o} = T_{c,i}$.